# creating a dictionary-like collection of values in an oracle package spec

Tags: plsql

Let's say I have a package spec. that stores constant values, which are extensively used in other packages (their procedures mainly) - so stuff like custom error messages, specific values, even lists like

`TYPE myTableType IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100); 
 myObj mytype := NEW myTableType ('value1','value2')`

I'd however now like to add a whole "dictionary" structure to it now - so a list of key-> value pairs in that package.

Seems I cannot initialise a table of records in that section, as already asked here:
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3A0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:14334298866128
and it seems a table of objects mentioned in the link is not a solution for me either. Not sure what would be a best workaround of some sort.

Any ideas ?

Comment: More context is needed to offer help on a solution, but you might want to review [Associative Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CHDEIDIC). This is the key-value pair type in PL/SQL, very similar to dictionaries or hash maps in other languages.

Comment: How would I initialise an associative array in the mentioned package block ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a package specification

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE example IS

   TYPE assoc_array_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);

   g_const_array assoc_array_type;

   PROCEDURE dummy_proc (i_var NUMBER);
END example;
/
```

You can initialize the associate array of constants as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY example IS

   PROCEDURE dummy_proc (i_var NUMBER) IS
   BEGIN
      dbms_output.put_line(g_const_array('key_1'));
   END dummy_proc;

BEGIN
   g_const_array('key_1') := 'value_1';
   g_const_array('key_2') := 'value_2';
   g_const_array('key_3') := 'value_3';
END example;
/
```

To test, compile spec and body and then call dummy_proc, which will print `value_1` to the console. Associative arrays can also be indexed by binary_integer or pls_integer for different needs.

EDIT: This second package shows that you can reference the public array and get the values from initialization in other packages.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE example_2 IS

   PROCEDURE dummy_proc (i_key VARCHAR2);

END example_2;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY example_2 IS

   PROCEDURE dummy_proc (i_key VARCHAR2) IS
   BEGIN
      dbms_output.put_line(example.g_const_array(i_key));
   END dummy_proc;

END example_2;
/

BEGIN
   example_2.dummy_proc('key_1');
END;
/
```

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention one important thing.
If I do it your way, then I fear the g_const_array values will not be visible in other packages, since the package body from what I read is a section that is "private" in terms of scope.
My package therefore does not have a package body at all.

Comment: ok, one idea pops in my mind - I can add a function that would in a way mimick a getter - create what I want in it's body, the function is public if I add it to the package spec., I can then return my table of records with that function.

Comment: The package body is in fact "private", but you are confusing the initialization with the actual variable. The initialization code runs when the package is first touched, putting values into the public array. It can in fact be used by other packages.

Comment: Oh! Now I get it. Didn't notice that independent BEGIN in the PACKAGE BODY. Good to know that's how packages are parsed.
Thanks a lot, that helps indeed :)